# AppEngine feature working in local dev server but not on live web server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have set up an AppEngine account to host a WorldKit based mapping project http://worldkit.org/  I have gotten it *almost* working, but the one last thing I am unable to get working is the map annotations feature, which is a large part of what I hope to achieve.  At first, I thought it might be due to the fact that the WorldKit download comes with a few PHP scripts, and I know that GAE doesn't host PHP, but I have been systematically removing pieces from the default package until I am left with only .html, .css, .xml, .js, image files, and a single .swf which serves as the main application.  The weird part is that annotations work perfectly using the local dev server, but when I deploy it live, the map displays fine, just with no annotations.  Annotations are provided to the application via a GeoRSS feed, which for now I am providing as a static, read-only file, but I may see about updating it live in the future.  Here is my app.yaml

```
application: parallelworldsmaps
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "30d"

handlers:

- url: /(.*\.css)
  mime_type: text/css
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.css)

- url: /(.*\.html)
  mime_type: text/html
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.html)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.ico)
  mime_type: image/x-icon
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ico)
  expiration: "7d"

- url: /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.js)

- url: /(.*\.json)
  mime_type: application/json
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.json)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.m4v)
  mime_type: video/m4v
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.m4v)

- url: /(.*\.mp4)
  mime_type: video/mp4
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.mp4)

- url: /(.*\.(ogg|oga))
  mime_type: audio/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(ogg|oga))

- url: /(.*\.ogv)
  mime_type: video/ogg
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ogv)

- url: /(.*\.otf)
  mime_type: font/opentype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.otf)

- url: /(.*\.rss)
  mime_type: application/rss+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.rss)
  expiration: "1h"

- url: /(.*\.(svg|svgz))
  mime_type: images/svg+xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(svg|svgz))

- url: /(.*\.swf)
  mime_type: application/x-shockwave-flash
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.swf)

- url: /(.*\.ttf)
  mime_type: font/truetype
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.ttf)

- url: /(.*\.txt)
  mime_type: text/plain
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.txt)

- url: /(.*\.webm)
  mime_type: video/webm
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.webm)

- url: /(.*\.xml)
  mime_type: application/xml
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xml)
  expiration: "1h"

# image files
- url: /(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

# audio files
- url: /(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(mid|midi|mp3|wav))  

# windows files
- url: /(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(doc|exe|ppt|rtf|xls))

# compressed files
- url: /(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bz2|gz|rar|tar|tgz|zip))

# index files
- url: /(.+)/
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /(.+)
  static_files: static/\1/index.html
  upload: static/(.+)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

# site root
- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /
  static_dir: static
```

All of my static files are contained in subfolders of the "static" directory.  To give a little better idea of how the app works, the .swf object accesses image files which it uses to render a map.  It then accesses an rss feed to render the annotations, which I have created in a static xml file and placed in the same directory as the .swf.  The rss feed contains coordinates, title, description, and an icon to be used as the map marker.  All of the map tiles display correctly, but none of the annotations do.  Based on attempts to reproduce this locally, it most likely means that the .swf is unable to access the .xml file which is located in the same folder.  I'm not sure what other information I can provide, but perhaps is the file not getting uploaded correctly or are there maybe weird permissions blocking things?  It's just weird and frustrating that it's working in the dev server but not on the real thing.

Comment: first off check in the logs for 404 errors on items that should be available.  Maybe some of your upload directives are wrong and not all of the assets are being uploaded .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a technical article on [how use and read the log files for GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging) - when we moved from dev to production we also had mysterious permission issues and by using the verbose logging, we were able to work around this.

Comment: Ok, well here's another weird issue.  I have /static/foo/index.html and /static/foo/bar/abunchofpics.jpg and I have it mapped so that if I navigate to /static/foo, I am served with /static/foo/index.html (actually, because of the way /static is mapped, it is transparent, so really I just type in /foo).  Anyway, my index.html references img src="bar/somepic.jpg", which doesn't show up when I view /foo, but it DOES show up when I view /foo/index.html (or /foo/) directly.  So I have the feeling that the way I am mapping my index.html files is somehow breaking relative paths.  Any thoughts there?

Comment: I've looked through the logs and I'm not seeing any 404's relating to any of the files involved in the annotations (though there were a few relating to the weird relative path mapping I mentioned above which I've fixed by disabling the /foo->/foo/index.html mapping and requiring a trailing slash /foo/).  So it doesn't seem to be a 404 issue.  Is there any way to simply browse the files that have been uploaded for the application?  That could help rule out upload rules as well...

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas.  No 404's in the logs, and I can download all of the files by manually typing the URL's.  I've even simplified my RSS to not use thumbnail images and just do text annotations, so the .rss file should be the *only* file affecting whether or not it works, and I know for a fact it got uploaded.  The only remotely similar issue I've had where files were uploaded properly but not displaying properly was due to setting an incorrect MIME type in app.yaml, but that's not the case here either.  Any ideas why my .swf can't read from a .rss file even in the same directory?